# Botão de formulário POST não funciona no Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Eu estou tentando enviar os dados de um formulário de Login pelo método POST, porem ele não esta indo de jeito algum, não aparece nada nenhum erro.

Segue o meu código

**Form**

```
<form class="form-group">
    {!! Form::open(['route' => 'user.login', 'method' => 'post']) !!}

    <div class="form-group">
      {!! Form::text('username',null,['class'=>'form-control form-control-user', 'id'=> 'exampleInputEmail','placeholder'=>'Usuário']) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      {!! Form::password('password',['class'=>'form-control form-control-user','placeholder'=>'Senha']) !!}
    </div>

    <a>
      {!! Form::submit('Entrar',['class'=>'btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block']) !!}
    </a>

    {!! Form::close() !!}
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use App\Repositories\UserRepository;
use App\Validators\UserValidator;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    private $repository;
    private $validator;


    public function __construct(UserRepository $repository, UserValidator $validator)
    {
        $this->repository = $repository;
        $this->validator  = $validator;
    }

    public function auth()
    {
        echo "Auth Method";
    }
}
```

**Rotas**

```
<?php
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });
    // Rotas para Login do Usuário
    Route::get('/login', ['uses' =>'Controller@fazerLogin']);
    Route::post('/login', ['as'=>'user.login','uses' => 'DashboardController@auth']);
```

Comment: `public function auth(Request $request)` já tentou colocar assim e buscas as informações enviadas `$request->all()`?

Comment: Agora apareceu um erro: Declaration of App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController::auth(Illuminate\Http\Request $request) should be compatible with App\Http\Controllers\Controller::auth(App\Http\Controllers\Request $request)

Comment: Você definiu esse método no seu controller base?

Comment: Isso é erro de `namespace` no qual o correto é `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`

Comment: <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Repositories\UserRepository;
use App\Validators\UserValidator;


class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    private $repository;
    private $validator;


    public function __construct(UserRepository $repository, UserValidator $validator)
    {
        $this->repository = $repository;
        $this->validator  = $validator;
    }

    public function auth(Request $request)
    {
        echo "Auth Method";
    }
}

Comment: Ainda continua o erro.

Comment: `App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController::auth(Illuminate\Http\Request $request)` renomei esse método do seu `controller` agora que vi ... coloque `authenticate`, porque no `Controller` já tem um método com o mesmo nome @FabianoF mude as rotas também quando mudar o nome do método